# Load Script tag into Angular that loads another script

Tags: javascript, angular

We have a requirement to load a JS widget from a UCaaS provider on our Angular website to provide chat features. The snippet the provided was

```
<script>
  var webchat;
  ((window, document, node, props, configs) => {
    if (window.ChatSDK) {
      console.error("SDK already included");
      return;
    }
    var divContainer = document.createElement("div");
    divContainer.id = node;
    document.body.appendChild(divContainer);
    var src = <https://chatsdk.ucass.com/chatsdk.js;>
    var script = document.createElement("script");
    var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
    script.type = "text/javascript";
    script.charset = "UTF-8";
    script.id = "webchatscript";
    script.src = src;
    script.async = true;
    firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(script, firstScriptTag);
    script.onload = () => {
      webchat = ChatSDK(node, props);
      webchat.init(configs);
    };
  })(
    window,
    document,
    "Webchat",
    { flowId: "123", accountId: "", region: "td-us-1" },
    { enableEmoji: true, enableUserInput: true }
  );
</script>
```

so putting this into the src of a script tag obviously doesn't work because its a function so the  was that whole block of code and that would not work so what I have now is trying to recreate it

```
 let webchat;
let ChatSDK: any;
let script = this.render.createElement('script');
script.src = 'https://chatsdk.ucaas.com/chatsdk.js';
script.type = 'text/javascript';
script.charset = 'UTF-8';
script.id = 'webchatscript';
script.async = true;

script.onload = () => {
  (function blah() {
    webchat = ChatSDK('Webchat', {
      flowId: '123',
      accountId: '',
      region: 'us-1',
    });
    webchat.init({ enableEmoji: true, enableUserInput: true });
  })();

  console.log(ChatSDK); //undefined 
};

this.render.appendChild(this._document.body, script);
```

I am able to confirm the script tag is in the body, I am seeing the js bundles get downloaded from the providers CDN and everything looks fine just the SDK is not found and thus not initialized - could someone help me understand what I am doing wrong

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `DOCUMENT` and call this method in `ngOnInit` of the `app.component.ts`:

```
constructor(private document: DOCUMENT) {}
...
const scriptElement = this.document.createElement('script');
...
this.document.body.appendChild(scriptElement);
```

Another way - try to use `angular.json` -> architect -> build -> options -> scripts sections with `inject: true`. Save first code example to the JS file and setup in this config.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks this works but also wanted Angular to be able to control it. Example on certain routes hide etc.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone comes on this later - I found I did overengineer it

here is what I did (selected code parts)

```
import { DOCUMENT} from '@angular/common';
import { Renderer2 } from '@angular/core';

  constructor(
    @Inject(DOCUMENT) private _document: Document,
    private render: Renderer2) {}
```

and then a method that can be called from where Onit,etc

```
    setupChatWidget() {
   
let script = this.render.createElement('script');
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    script.innerHTML = `...code here minus the <script> tags from the provider`;
    this.render.appendChild(this._document.body, script);
  }
```